# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties') : NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, nestjs, nest

Upon trying to generate a new module in NestJS with the Nest CLI, I get this error. This is also the case for when I try to generate kind of nest schematic. It would be really helpful if someone knew where this stems from.

This is on a Windows 10.

I tried the command - `nest g module <module-name>`. This is also the case for `nest g controller <controller-name>` etc.

The error that I got is the following -

```
> nest g module task
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')

Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:module --name=task --no-dry-run --no-skip-import --language="ts" --source-root="src" --spec --no-flat --spec-file-suffix="spec"
```

Comment: npm i -g @nestjs/schematics

Comment: The problem still persists

Comment: I don't recommend using the CLI globally like that. Try the local one instead `npx nest g module task`